# good way to do countdown timer in online exam

Tags: javascript, web, countdown

Hi I have a plan to make web based online exam.

For the timer implementation, which is best and good practice:
 1. Do XHR to get exam time, and then do countdown in client side
 2. Do XHR to get exam time multiple time
 3. ??

Is anyone have another idea?

Comment: solution 1 would be somewhat efficient.. Doing a bullet request 
1. saves time 
2. prevents putting heavy load the server

Comment: Combination of both 1 and 2 will be better. To avoid client side hack.After some time interval ask server for time remain if the client time is near to server fetch time (say 5second offset time considering XHR request delay) then leave client time as-is else update the client time to match with server time

Comment: @repzero Is there any possibilities client do some hack with the time? In real project which one is commonly used? thank you

Comment: @ShoaibKonnur I think its good option. Thank you, but dou u know, in real project which one is commonly used?